# Merge two regex and match strings but not with period (or dot or full stop)

Tags: php, regex

I'm using PHP. I need to validate the following kind of strings:

```
B223213FCF@COM
B90TY13AAA@DE
232342342X@CO.UK
```

Which patterns is:

- "B" followed by 2 digits and 7 alphanumeric values
- 9 digits and as tenth character either a "X" or another digit

After the `@` the following domain extensions are accepted:

```
com.au, ca, cn, com, de, es, fr, in, it, co.jp, com.mx, nl, co.uk
```

I managed to work out the following two regex which somehow work:

```
/B[0-9]{2}[0-9A-Z]{7}|[0-9]{9}(X|0-9])

@(com\.au|ca|cn|com|de|es|fr|in|it|co\.jp|com\.mx|nl|co\.uk)/i
```

The issues I'm facing are:

- I don't understand how to merge the two regex in a single one
- The second regex needs to be fixed to **not** match dots as in this case:

  ```
  B223213FCF@COM.
  ```

because the above string (with the dot at the end) still validates. The domain extension must be considered as exact word I suppose.

Comment: use anchors? `/^pattern1@pattern2$/i`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can merge the two regexps as

```
^(?:B\d{2}\w{7}|\d{9}X)@(?:co\.(?:uk|jp)|com(?:\.(?:au|mx))?|c[an]|de|es|fr|i[nt]|nl)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wV2vB7/1)

I introduced anchors `^` and `$` to make sure the pattern is applied to the entire string, added two alternatives before `@` (`(?:B\d{2}\w{7}` and `\d{9}X)`), and shrunk the TLDs to make the regex more efficient (since that way fewer backtracking steps are necessary).

The regex matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:B\d{2}\w{7}|\d{9}X)` - two alternatives:

  - `B\d{2}\w{7}` - `B` followed with 2 digits followed with 2 word characters
  - `|` - or...
  - `\d{9}X` - nine digits followed with `X`
- `@` - a literal `@` sign
- `(?:co\.(?:uk|jp)|com(?:\.(?:au|mx))?|c[an]|de|es|fr|i[nt]|nl)` - the list of TLD alternatives
- `$` - end of string

**NOTE**

If the first part up to `@` must be case sensitive and the second one should not, omit the general `/i` modifier at the end of the regex declaration and use the `(?i:...)` syntax to force the second part to be case insensitive:

```
'~^(?:B\d{2}\w{7}|\d{9}X)@(?i:co\.(?:uk|jp)|com(?:\.(?:au|mx))?|c[an]|de|es|fr|i[nt]|nl)$~'
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wV2vB7/2)

Comment: Your explanation was very useful!